# SQLite AUTO_INCREMENT id field is upside down on the program

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

here a pic to a better understand
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6tpl.png

```
def consult(self):
    book = self.cuadro_blanco_cliente.get_children()
    for elementos in book:
        self.cuadro_blanco_cliente.delete(elementos)
    query = "SELECT Nro, codigo, nombre, nfc, telefono, celular,direccion FROM clientes"#
    rows = self.run_query(query)#query
    for row in rows:
        self.cuadro_blanco_cliente.insert('',0, text=row[1],values=row)
```

Comment: `If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined` See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_order_by_clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some lines to the code, and fixed the problem, begin from 1 now

```
for row in rows:
        id = row[0]
        self.cuadro_blanco_cliente.insert("",END, id, text=id, values=row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't on the id field, is in the way you are using to add the rows on the display. You are traversing the array from id 1 to n, but adding the rows always to the beginning, making it look like the ids go from n to 1.

Try adding this at the end of your query clause:

```
"... ORDER BY id DESC"
```

This way, you will insert first, the last element, and then insert the other rows before the last, and so on, securing the fetched rows are ordered by id.

Comment: This assumes that the rows are ordered by id in the first place, which is an invalid assumption unless the query has an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: thanks for your support, if I use for row in rows[::-1]: on my code it gives me, TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable